How to do rolling reboot's in AWS SSM?
I'm currently using AWS SSM to patch and update our instances. The process involves multiple steps: first, I stop services on all instances before moving to the next step, which includes running 'install' and 'rebootifneeded' commands through aws:runpatchbaseline. The challenge is with our production environment—we cannot have all instances down simultaneously. Currently I'm using multiple maintenance windows, but I'm looking for a way to automate this process across instances one at a time. Is it possible to handle this via a Lambda function or jenkins job?
Currently, Im using multiple maintenance windows and tried to use a run book.
